# Upload excel file from using angular js and WebAPI

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload an excel file using Angular js, send the string data to Webapi and then convert it to file. However when i try to open this file in explorer, it says file is corrupted.

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="chooseDocument()" class="btn btn-primary ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>&nbsp;Upload
</div>
<input id="chooseDocument" type="file" class="form-control" style="display: none;" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().addDocument(this)" />
```

Angular Js:

```
 $scope.chooseDocument = function () {
    var dialog = $("#chooseDocument");
    dialog.trigger("click");
}

$scope.addDocument = function (dialog) {
    var files = dialog.files;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    function readFile() {
        var file = files[0];
        reader.onloadend = function () {              
            uploadExcel(file.name, reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    readFile(0);
}

function uploadExcel(filename, file) {
    $http.post(getUrl('api/User/UploadExcel'), { DocumentName: filename, DocumentContent: file }).then(function (response) {
      //do something

    }, function (errors) {
        //do Something
    });

};
```

WebAPI:

```
 File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\MyFile\" + document.DocumentName, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(document.DocumentContent));

 document.DocumentContent has value "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC82fymuQEAACIIAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRf..."
```

Comment: I am not suprised, why don't you just upload the file and what makes you think that it is asci encoded text?

Comment: try uploading with content-type =undefined.

Comment: @BenRobinson it works fine for an image, hence tried to make it work for excel. What exactly you mean by upload the file.

Comment: @JSJ where exaclty to do that?

Comment: under header properties.

Comment: @BenRobinson any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is document.DocumentContent is in **base64** format.
spliting the data on comma after base64**,** gave the appropriate excel file.

WebAPI:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Convert.FromBase64String(document.DocumentContent.Split((",").ToCharArray())[1]));
```